# PYTHON: Most effeciant way to search through a txt database

Tags: python, database

What is the most efficient way to search through a .txt database? Mine is over 460 mb and it takes about 10 seconds to find the string and print the line

Here is my code:

```
import re
userName = raw_input("USER: ")
with open("mcdata.txt", "r") as txtFile:
    for line in txtFile:
        if re.match(userName + ':', line):
            print line
```

I am not using `break` because there are sometimes multiple lines.
Any way to make this faster?

Comment: replace `re.match` line with `if userName+':' in line:`

Comment: When I do that, I get results that are not exact to my search query.

Comment: I don't know if it will go faster, but try `if line.startswith(userName+':'):`. Also, if you want the fastest linear search, try `egrep "^$userName:" mcdata.txt` from the shell (assuming that you are using Linux orUNIX or a UNIX shell in Windows.)

Answer (score -1):

Your algorithm is known as *linear search,* so called because it takes time to complete that is proportional to the number of records. If your usernames are stored in random order, you can't make it any faster.

**However,** there is an entire field of computer science dedicated to search algorithms, programs that find text in an array of text.

One way to speed it up would be to keep the usernames in alphabetical order, then use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the record. This takes O(log n) time.

Even faster would be to use a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which takes O(1) time, but the trade-off is that it takes up *much* more memory. This is impossible in your case, since 460MB will put a significant dent in the amount of RAM the machine has available.